# Selecting multiple elements with Jquery, but adding a class only to one of them with addClass()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a few divs with the 'clickable' class. If one of the divs is clicked, then i want the class 'clicked' to be added to the element, but only to that particular div that was clicked. Currently my code adds the class to all elements with the 'clickable' class, since i'm selecting all of them. How do i add it only to the specific div that was clicked, without writing code for each div?

HTML:

```
<div class="size m-size clickable">M</div>
<div class="size m-size clickable">L</div>
<div class="size m-size clickable">XL</div>
<div class="size m-size clickable">XXL</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function () {
    $('.clickable').addClass('clicked');
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code to:

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
})
```

Where "$(this)" corresponds to the event target element.

You can also look into the [toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) function.